# MySQL - Invert Date Spans in table; create unavailability table from availability table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of available dates, and I would like to make a table of unavailable dates from it. Seems like it should be pretty simple, can do it in php no problem, but can't figure out how to do it in a MySQL query.

Source table:
(opens is the date someone checks out; closes is the day someone checks in)

```
+------------+------------+
|   opens    |   closes   |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-12-03 | 2015-12-09 |
| 2016-01-03 | 2016-01-06 |
| 2016-01-08 | 2016-01-15 |
| 2016-01-16 | 2016-02-08 |
| 2016-02-21 | 2016-02-27 |
| 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-06 |
| 2016-03-10 | 2016-12-03 |
+------------+------------+
```

Query should return:

```
+------------+------------+
|   checkin  |   checkout |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-12-09 | 2016-01-03 |
| 2016-01-06 | 2016-01-08 |
| 2016-01-15 | 2016-01-16 |
| 2016-02-08 | 2016-02-21 |
| 2016-02-27 | 2016-03-01 |
| 2016-03-06 | 2016-03-10 |
+------------+------------+
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Closes as checkin,
 (SELECT OPENS FROM T WHERE OPENS>T1.Closes ORDER BY OPENS LIMIT 1) as checkout
FROM T T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT OPENS FROM T WHERE OPENS>T1.Closes)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35ed60/4)</kbd>